# Script and css linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when my index at here [image]

the script url was

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.fullPage.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

when i move the index file to front folder  > untitled 3

which is here [image]

and the url change to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

but it dint work.
Even the link use browse and select the script file and url given by the system

help~
is that any setting need to change

Comment: Are you using a local webserver or are you testing your stuff using `file://` protocol?

Comment: normal preview in chrome

Comment: using file:// protocol

Comment: @connexo file:///C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/new%20media/Untitled-3.html

Comment: Did you try `href="./jquery.fullPage.css"`?

Comment: yes . tried , but as default should be jquery.fullPage.css .

Comment: Try using absolute path then. `file:///C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/new%20media/css/jquery.fullPage.css`

Comment: do u mean move the js and css script to the css folder and relink them ? tried , not working too.. if create another empty folder in the new media and move the index inside , its work , and the url like before 

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.fullPage.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong in your include mechanism. Open web console in FF/Chrome broser while loading the html file. It will show you a request being made to load the js/css file, with the actual/complete path; and also show the result of loading.